# How do I get rid of the Cisco CP one-time user message on a Cisco 2901 router?

Tags: cisco

I get this message on a new 2901 Cisco router:

> ---
>
> Cisco Configuration Professional (Cisco CP) is installed on this
>   device and it provides the default username "cisco" for  one-time use.
>   If you have already used the username "cisco" to login to the router
>   and your IOS image supports the "one-time" user option, then this
>   username has already expired. You will not be able to login to the
>   router with this username after you exit this session.
>
> It is strongly suggested that you create a new username with a
>   privilege level of 15 using the following command.
>
> `username <myuser> privilege 15 secret 0 <mypassword>`
>
> Replace  and  with the username and password you
>   want to use.
>
> ---

It appears every time I login and everytime I `show run`. I already set up my username. How do I turn it off?

Comment: The commands should be "username <myuser> privilege 15 secret 0 <mypassword>" and "no username cisco".

Comment: @Skaperen - that would be the markdown editor eating the extra words as if they were HTML tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this : https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2001950

it may be related to the various banners of cisco configuration
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/frf004.html#wp1017571

try to find out if your 'banners' configurations contains the message

Answer (score 1):

You"ll need to first remove the default banner which you can do in config mode in the CLI by issuing:

```
no banner login
no banner exec
```

Then you can configure your own.

Remember to save the running-configuration to the startup configuration once you are happy with the changes you have made, otherwise they will be lost the next time you power cycle the switch.